# Where did we use local compactness and how is Urysohn's lemma used?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Notation $Ba_X$ is the sigma-algebra of Baire sets, i.e. the smallest sigma-algebra generated by the compact $G_{\delta}$ sets of $X$.

**lemma** : Assume that $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. Then $Ba_X$ is the smallest $σ$-algebra relative to which all functions in $C_c(X)$ are measurable.

**proof** : We verify first that each $f∈C_c(X)$ is measurable[$Ba_X$], and we can restrict ourselves to the collection of nonnegative functions since it generates C_c(X) as a vector space. For the other direction Assume then that $f∈C_c(X)$ is nonnegative and observe that $(f≥α)=⋂_{n=1}^{\infty}(f>α−1n)$ is a compact $G_δ$ set for $α>0$, while $(f≥α)=X$ for $α<0$. Thus $f$ is measurable [BaX].

Assume that all the functions in $C_c(X)$ are measurable [S] for some σ-algebra S. We need to show that every compact $G_δ$ set belongs to S. Indeed, assume that $K=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$ is compact,where $G_n$ is open for every $n∈N$, and use Urysohn’s lemma to produce functions $f_n∈C_c(X)$ such that $χ_K≤f_n≤χ_{G_n}$.The result follows from the equality $K=\cap_n(f_n>0)$

But in this proof I don't really understand two things:

- where did we use that $X$ is locally compact?
- How did we get $(f_n>0)=G_n$ since the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma#Formal_statement) for Urysohn's lemma seems to say in general we cannot require $f(x)\neq 0$ outside the closed sets we separate?

Answer (score 1):

(1) We used local compactness to get that $X$ is normal, so that Urysohn's Lemma applies.

(2) The proof didn't say that $(f_n>0)=G_n$. But the definition of $f_n$ immediately gives that $K\subseteq (f_n>0)\subseteq G_n$. Taking te intersection over all $n$, we get $K\subseteq\bigcap_n(f_n>0)\subseteq K$.

Comment: $X$ might not be normal, though; the fact that $K$ is compact (and not just closed) is crucial to the argument.  (You can instead use the normality of the 1-point compactification of $X$.)

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right. So local compactness is used either to ensure that the one-point compactification is a Hausdorff space or to prove Urysohn's Lemma directly without mentioning normality (?).

Comment: Yeah, one of the two, depending on how you formulate it.  It is possible to directly prove a version of Urysohn's lemma for locally compact Hausdorff spaces (which requires one of the sets to be compact, rather than just closed), but I find it cleaner to just pass to the 1-point compactification.

Comment: I understand point (2) now, thank you for that. Could you give some more details as to how to use the one-point compactification for point (1)?

Comment: The one-point compactification $X^+$ of any space $X$  is compact; if $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, then $X^+$ is a Hausdorff space. Since all  compact Hausdorff spaces are normal, Urysohn's Lemma applies and provides the functions $f_n$ used in the proof.